# Basic data format convert in java

Tags: java, date, datetime-format, date-formatting, localdate

I have a JSP which has data picker and the output returns datastring in dd-MM-yyyy format.

now I want the output exactly in the date time format -> 2019-01-01T01:01:59Z.

I guess this is from simple date format to date time format . I tried and its throwing error.
here is my code. formatedate2 is failing.

```
DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH);
    DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2018-04-10T04:00:00.000Z", inputFormatter);
    String formattedDate = outputFormatter.format(date);
    LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.parse("12-10-2019", outputFormatter);
    String formattedDate2 = inputFormatter.format(date2);


    System.out.println(formattedDate2);
```

can someone guide me on ho to accomplish this. Appreciate your great help

Comment: These formatters are for parsing and formatting data, not for creating missing data. You have a `LocalDate`, that can't be formatted in a format requiring time data.

Comment: What are you asking is not really clear, can you please try to show some input and output

Comment: Hi ..Thanks for the reply...My input is 12-10-2019 and i need output as 2019-10-12T01:01:59Z – TTT ... is this achievable?

Comment: you can get it but what about the time in output date? @TTT

Comment: Can the time of day in the output be chosen freely? Should it always be 01:01:59 UTC? Or where should the program get it from?

Comment: I edited your tags. The dateformat and simpledateformat tags are for old and outdated Java classes that you have wisely chosen not to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This takes your LocalDate and converts it to a LocalDateTime using LocalTime.MIN which is 00:00. We then convert the LocalDateTime to a ZonedDateTime using atZone with a ZoneId of UTC. We then format that ZonedDateTime to the format you want using format(). I hope this helps.

```java
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2018-04-10");

        LocalDateTime localDateTime = date.atStartOfDay();

        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));

        System.out.println(zonedDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")));
```

**Output: 2018-04-10T00:00:00.000Z**

Comment: Hi My input is 12-10-2019 and i need output as 2019-10-12T01:01:59Z

Comment: It's not possible to obtain time from a date if doesn't exist. Please update your question to be more clear.

Comment: if this is not possible can i have a data picker in jsp which comes with time?

Comment: Updated answer, let me know if that helps.

Comment: Instead of `date.atTime(LocalTime.MIN)` you could also use `date.atStartOfDay()`. That method is maybe a bit easier to read.

Comment: A couple of yet simpler and/or more correct options: (1) Pass the zone as argument to `atStartOfDay` to obtain a `ZonedDateTime` directly. Or (2) instead of getting a `ZonedDateTime` use `localDateTime.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)` to obtain an `OffsetDateTime`. Formatting it goes the same way as before.

Comment: Also hardcoding `'Z'` in the format pattern string is incorrect even though it happens to give the correct result in this case. Use pattern letter uppercase `X` for the offset, it prints Z for zero as you require it.